# Label position between series in Highcharts polar chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to position custom labels on the outside of a polar chart but can't figure out any way to do it. Please image below for what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Doesn't have to use the actual series labels but haven't found anything else that can be positioned relative to the actual chart (top level labels can be positioned anywhere but only using absolute left and top).

Have also tried changing the pointPlacement and tickmarkPlacement to "between" which sort of works but it rotates the actual chart so I get a diamond shape instead of a square, the effect I'm after would be more like rotating the labels and leaving the ticks in place.

Comment: You can define the position of the labels in many ways - the best might depend on what chart's features you use. One way - you can use gridlines' group to position custom labels relative to it - http://jsfiddle.net/cfam7ztf/

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Works great, do you want to add an answer and I'll mark it?

Comment: Sure, I have post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN such case custom labels can be positioned relative to grid line group.

Method for drawing the labels:

```
function drawLabels () {
  let labels = this.customLabels,
      bbox = this.xAxis[0].gridGroup.getBBox(),
     positions = [
       [bbox.x + bbox.width / 2, bbox.y],
       [bbox.x + bbox.width, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2],
       [bbox.x + bbox.width / 2, bbox.y + bbox.height],
       [bbox.x, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2]
     ];

  if (!labels) {
    labels = this.customLabels = ['lab1', 'lab2', 'lab3', 'lab4'].map(text => this.renderer.label(text, 0, -9999).add().attr({zIndex: 4}));
  }

  labels.forEach((label, i) => {
    label.align({
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      width: label.width,
      height: label.height
    }, null, {
      x: positions[i][0],
      y: positions[i][1],
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    });
  });
}
```

Draw labels on load/redraw:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      load: drawLabels,
      redraw: drawLabels
    }
  },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/d6y1bn31/

[image]